# Share code between package.js in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, package

I have a number of packages, with a package.js file inside each. In those package.js files, I have a couple of helper functions. Right now, when I create a new package, I have to duplicate those helper functions.

Is there a way to put those helper functions in one place and use it from every package.js?

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted you, it is a legit question. I don't know if it is possible but as a direction to explore is to use `uniload` - js file in meteor/tools that allows you to load Meteor packages into a node script

Comment: I agree with you, modularizing code for `package.js` is extraordinarily bad because you can't quite access NPM packages and you can't quite access Meteor code. I also have this problem in https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs/blob/master/package.js.

Answer (score 1):

Found this question randomly over google,

just create a global helpers package for example: `username:global-heleprs`

example code:

```
heleprs = {
  formattedTimeStramp: function (date) {
    return moment(date).format('dddd');
  },
  more...
}
```

use `api.export('helpers', ['server', 'client']);` to export helpers object to make it available outside the package

if you want to use it on different package just do on this your different package package.js file it will give you access to `helpers`

`api.use('username:global-heleprs', ['client','server']);`

if you want to use it on the meteor application itself on any file (outside of packages)

`meteor add username:global-helpers`

p.s if you don't add it using `meteor add username:global-helpers` the access to the helpers is only to the packages that require it with `api.use` that's pretty good avoid sharing the helpers with the main app.

Comment: @kyll added another clarification you can add it to the application only or for package use only (don't do meteor add)